# How to save and close the applications using cmd or atleast using java program?

Tags: java, file, process, cmd, kill

I can kill some applications in cmd using command taskkill /F /IM program_name.exe
But before killing any applications i want to save whatever the work has been done. 
EX: kill the Microsoft word, but before that I want to save it. How can I do it through cmd?

Give me an idea. If it is not possible, even through Java also ok for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

Comment: Thanks i'm working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to terminate the program in Java (in Windows):

```
    try {
       Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM word.exe");
    } catch (RuntimeException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Be note that this can't even save data. Use java.awt.Robot mentioned by Elliott Frisch. (I hadn't use that before)

Comment: yes Anthony we should use robot class to simulate mouse movements.

Answer (score 0):

`Taskkill` without the `/f` asks the program to close, like you clicked `File - Exit`. Most programs will ask if you want to save the current file.

With `/f` it terminates the program without asking it. Nothing will be saved.

Remove `/f` from the command.